# Angular 6 two dependant asynchronous call in for loop

Tags: angular, http

I've a problem with two asynchronous call in a for loop. 
This is the scenario: I've an array of ids and for each of them I need to call a rest service. With the response of this service I need to do various operations and then call a second rest service. I use the response of the second service to do stuff. Finally I need to do operations only when all element of the array are processed.

I found a solution like this:

```
let i = 0;
of(...this.idsArray).pipe(
    map(id => {
        return this.myService.getItemById(id).subscribe()
    }),
    tap(data => this.item = data; //How get first response here??? ),
    map(resp => {
        return this.myService.getCatInfo(this.item.cat).subscribe()
    }),
    tap(res => this.cat = res; //How get second response here???)
).subscribe();
```

I'm not sure the code is correct but the problem is how I can get the responses of services and use them in tap functions?
Thanks

EDIT:

I'm trying to use concatMap and I get a better behaviour but it still doesn't work:

```
let i = 0;
of(...this.idsArray).pipe(
    concatMap(id => {
        console.log('first step');
        return this.myService.getItemById(id).subscribe()
    }),
    tap(data => {this.item = data; console.log('second step')}),
    concatMap(resp => {
        return this.myService.getCatInfo(this.item.cat)
    }),
    tap(res => {this.cat = res; console.log('third step')})
).subscribe();
```

The output is:

```
first step
second step
first step
third step
second step
first step
third step
second step
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using the [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator. This will add the new subscriptions you need to http observables behind the scenes.

Here is a rough idea of what it could look like with your code:

```
of(...this.idsArray).pipe(
    mergeMap(id => {
        return this.myService.getItemById(id);
    }),
    tap(data => this.item = data; //How get first response here??? ),
    mergeMap(resp => {
        return this.myService.getCatInfo(this.item.cat);
    }),
    tap(res => this.cat = res; //How get second response here???)
).subscribe();
```

Inside of tap, you can also use the debugger to see what you have at that point.

```
tap(data => {
  debugger;
  this.item = data;
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply OneLunch Man, but in this way the order isn't correct. The steps aren't executed sequentially. The sequence is: at first all the firstMergeMap (one for each items in array), then all the tap instructions and finally all the second tap instructions...

Comment: At this point, they should be different streams executing in parallel (please correct me if I'm wrong). Can you verify individual sequential order by adding an if (id === myId) { debugger; } at each step to watch a specific ID and verify it's being handled correctly?

Comment: Using mergeMap sequence isn't correct. mergeMap executes all iterations in loop and then pass the control to first tap. So, I think the only way to respect the sequence is to use map. The problem is that in first tap I get an Observable and if I try to subscribe it, the sequence comes wrong again...

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example of what you have?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **switchMap** to avoid subscribe inside subscribe

```
of(...this.idsArray).pipe(
 switchMap(id => {
     return this.myService.getItemById(id);
 }),
switchMap(data => this.myService.getCatInfo(data.cat)),
tap(res => this.cat = res; //How get second response here???)
).subscribe();
```

Comment: data in switchMap is an Observable, I can't do data.cat

Comment: The first "map" needs to either merge or switch since the service return is an observable.

Comment: switchMap doesn't respect the sequence in loop, it executes all the iterations in first block and the the rest. The only way is to use map to get the correct sequence order.